# setting file path in javascript through codeigniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter-2

i am using code igniter 2.1. and
i am using a js file to show a tree view. the view is showing correctly but the linked images are not showing.
in the view i am calling a js file named dtree.js
there the image paths are set as:

```
this.icon = {

        root            : 'images/Crystal_Clear_user.gif',

        folder          : 'img/folder.gif',

        folderOpen      : 'img/folderopen.gif',

        node            : 'img/page.gif',

        empty           : 'img/empty.gif',
};
```

and when i am debugging my code in browser it shows that it can't find the actual file path.
the browser reads the code as

```
<img id="jmytree0" src="img/nolines_plus.gif" alt />
```

how can i fix this problem. i mean how do change the js files

```
'images/Crystal_Clear_user.gif'
```

this to work properly in codeigniter.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Append a "/" at the beginning of the path

```
this.icon = {

        root            : '/images/Crystal_Clear_user.gif',

        folder          : '/img/folder.gif',

        folderOpen      : '/img/folderopen.gif',

        node            : '/img/page.gif',

        empty           : '/img/empty.gif',
};
```

p.s. you list some images as "images" and some as "img" - is that correct?

Comment: i have tried that, but no luck. and to the answer of your question, yes that is correct. i have two folders named images and img

Comment: the code works as it is when i try it on raw php, but it creates problem when i integrate it with codeigniter.

Comment: where is your img & image directors relative to your domain? i.e. does www.mydomain.com/img/folder.gif show the image?